# Simplifying multiple OR Conditions

Tags: c, performance

I have following code:

```
if(IND_1 == 0 || IND_2 == 0 || IND_3 == 0 || IND_4 == 0 || IND_5 == 0 
        || IND_6 == 0 || IND_7 == 0 || IND_8 == 0 || IND_9 == 0 ) 
    Do something;
```

But the problem with this code I feel is taking lots of processing power.
So, I tried following format

```
if((IND_1,IND_2,IND_3)==0)
```

but didn't worked.

> Giving unexpected token error ","

Tried this format too:

```
if((IND_1||IND_2||IND_3||IND_4||IND_5||IND_6||IND_7||IND_8||IND_9) == 0 ) 
    printf("Apple");
```

It also didn't worked. No error. But not printing Apple.

Any other way of simplifying this code?
As I have this type of code with different variable 28 times, so thought to simply it. Also keeping the program processing power usage in mind.

Comment: *"But the problem with this code I feel is taking lots of processing power."* Don't trust your feelings. When in doubt, do a benchmark.

Comment: Use a single `int_32` to do your work and do a bit comparison.

Comment: *"So, I tried following format"* - And what gave you the notion it would work?

Comment: When dealing with a question about performance, context is important. There is simply not enough information for us to know how to improve it.

Comment: if((IND_1,IND_2,IND_3)==0) giving unexpected token error ","

Comment: @mimi Because it isn't valid in C.

Comment: @ameyCU Are you sure?

Comment: The `OR` one is the most optimised, if the first condition is `true` it wont even check the rest of them.

Comment: Why aren't you using an array? `int IND[10];` will ceratainly shorten and simplify your code. You can use a loop and a condition to check the member elements. BTW, you can use `if(!IND_1 || !IND_2 || !IND_3 || !IND_4 || !IND_5 || !IND_6 || !IND_7 || !IND_8 || !IND_9)` too

Comment: @unwind Havn't come across use of this in `if` condition.

Comment: array can slow the process more with lots of "for loop" calling, as I have this code 20 times separately.

Comment: If you know which checks are most likely to happen, sort your checks so that the most likely to happen is first. The if will stop checking as soon as it knows the truth of the if statement.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. Do you want to shorten and simplify your code or want to achieve greater performance? Or both?

Comment: @CoolGuy Both shorten & improved performance

Comment: "It also didn't worked". It can't. If you change the value to check you have to change the operator. `if ((A)==0||(B)==0)` --> `if (((A)&&(B))==0)`. If one of (A,B) is zero then the expression in the if clause is FALSE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't say your solution is bad in terms of processing power. Operations like comparing values and or'ing the solutions usually only take a few processor cycles an can easily be handled by modern CPUs. This means your solution is good this way and doesn't need to be changed.

Another possibility would be to multiply the values and check if the result is equal to 0, but this approach is probably a lot slower since multiplication takes usually more processor cycles than comparing values and or'ing them.

Answer (score 5):

> Any other way of simplifying this code?

What about:

```
if (!(IND_1 && IND_2 && ... && IND_n))
{
  /* Do something. */
  ...
```

Comment: I think this could better be formatted as an answer and not a rhetoric question. Just to prevent confusion.

Comment: @anatolyg: Oh well, it's an answer by definition, isn't it? ;-) and whether it's "simpler" sort of matters the way one looks at it.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
if((IND_1,IND_2,IND_3)==0)
```

uses the C comma operator inside the parentheses, which will:

- Evaluate `IND_1` and `IND_2`, throwing the result away
- Evaluate `IND_3`, and generate that as the result of the (sub)expression

That result is then compared  to 0, which it might or might not equal. The result of that comparison, however, depends *only* on the value of `IND_3`, so this is not at all what you want to do.

Unless you've profiled this so that you *know* the big chain of ORs is taking up too much time, leave it.

Otherwise you can perhaps re-sort the comparisons, since it will stop when the first `true` value is found, or pack them into an integer as was suggested in a comment.

Comment: It would be logical the way it works ( ex : as does with `return`) but it gives compilation error in this case.

Comment: @ameyCU [Not for me, it doesn't](https://godbolt.org/g/0i9BbF).

Comment: My bad. It did on online compiler (must be an old one I guess). It doesn't when compiled with c99 flag :)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't change the code - except for adding line breaks like:

```
if (IND_1 == 0 ||
    IND_2 == 0 ||
    ....
    IND_N == 0)
```

The way the code is written using `== 0` and `||` makes it very easy to read and understand what it is you want to achieve. That has a great value.

Using `&&` and omitting the `== 0` just makes the code harder to read. The compiler shouldn't care so there should be no gain in leaving out the `== 0`.

So my take is: Keep the current code.

The only reason that you should change something is if one variable is more likely to be zero than others. In that case you should place the "most likely to be zero" variables first.

Regarding this part:

```
if((IND_1||IND_2||IND_3||IND_4||IND_5||IND_6||IND_7||IND_8||IND_9) == 0 ) 
   printf("Apple");
```

You already wrote that it didn't work. The reason is that it's not equivalent to your original code. Instead it is equivalent to:

```
if((IND_1 == 0 && IND_2==0 && .... && IND_N==0) == 0 ) 
    printf("Apple");
```

So your rewrite actually ruined the logic!

This just underlines that you should avoid using "smart" tricks and just write your code in a natural way which is easy to read and understand.

Comment: Yes you are right. My simplifying actually changing the whole logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the amount to write when you use the right logic:

```
if((IND_1&&IND_2&&IND_3&&IND_4&&IND_5&&IND_6&&IND_7&&IND_8&&IND_9) == 0 ) 
  printf("Apple");
```

This isn't so good readable. The bars "|" look like more like a table. The logical AND operator `&&` doesn't improve this. So you could try this:

```
if((IND_1 && IND_2 && IND_3 && IND_4 && IND_5 &&
    IND_6 && IND_7 && IND_8 && IND_9) == 0 ) 
  printf("Apple");
```

But this doesn't affect the performance. In any case the CPU will stop evaluating the expression after the first IND_x is zero.